# How to download file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to download excel in java, but instead of downloading as File, it is returning as blob type.

I tried the below code to download the excel in java8.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@PostMapping(value = "/download-report", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getSrmTallyReportInExcel() {
    try {
        File file = /*assigning/creating my file here*/;
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "report.xlsx");
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(resource);
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

When i run in postman, instead of downloading file directly, it is returning the response in this format(�L������Pk�"�W��9�˰�) which i can download as excel file by clicking on Save as File.
But i wish to download directly without click that Save as File option. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Postman doesn't download anything, it's not a browser.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar if i try to downloading from swagger, it is saying `Unable to open file. The file may corrupted`. But the file downloaded through postman is working fine. Is there anything i need to handle in code for that ?

Comment: `File file = /*assigning/creating my file here*/` doesn't create a file, whatever may be in this initializer. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the wrong content type in the response. You are setting in to a binary (`MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`), so it is interpreted as a binary file by the browser. You should set it to what you already said in the `produces` attribute it returns, an Excel file: `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Answer (score 2):

No, what you send over HTTP is binary information, so you receive it as BLOB. It is up to a convention between the server and client to know that the information that you download is a file of a particular type. So, say if I am a server-side developer and I developed an end-point that reads and returns say a document in format PDF I should provide the information to a client that return type is file of type PDF. This could be done with headers but also as documentation. So, when a client invokes my end-point (s)he will receive a BLOB that the client needs to save as a file with .pdf extension.